# How to get value altLanguages and put that dynamically into a JSON, so it can be loaded into the Head

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Currently i am trying to get the value of altLanguages and output that dynamically in a JSON, so it can be injected into the head. The altLanguages are the meta attribute values that should be added before rendering the page to avoid the error (altLanguages is undefined). Anyone know how to do that.

```js
<template>
  <header class="site-header">
    <router-link to="/" class="logo">Example Site</router-link>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="menuLink in menuLinks" :key="menuLink.id">
          <prismic-link :field="menuLink.link">{{ $prismic.richTextAsPlain(menuLink.label) }}</prismic-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <alternate-languages :altLanguages="altLanguages" />
    <!-- <alternate-content :altLanguages="altLanguages" /> -->
  </header>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    id: { type: String, default: "" },
    altLanguages: { type: Array, default: () => ([]) }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      menuContent: [],
      menuLinks: [],
      // altLanguages: []
    };
  },

  methods: {
    async getMenu(lang) {
      //Query to get menu content
      const menuContent = await this.$prismic.client.getSingle("menu", {
        lang: lang
      });

      this.menuContent = menuContent;
      this.menuLinks = menuContent.data.menu_links;
    }
  },
  created() {
    // this.getLanguages(this.id);

    this.getMenu(this.$route.params.lang);
  },

  watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
      this.getMenu(to.params.lang);
    }
  }
  // beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
  //   console.log("new");
  //   this.getMenu(to.params.lang);
  //   next();
  // }
};
</script>


//expected output 

export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      title: 'My Title'
    }
  },
  // Usage with context the component
  head: {
    // To use "this" in the component, it is necessary to return the object through a function
    title: function () {
      return {
        inner: this.title
      }
    },
    meta: [
    // altLanguages should be output in here.....
      { name: 'description', content: 'My description', id: 'desc' }
    ]
  }
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: can you give an example of the expected output?

Comment: Ok check updated answer

Comment: `meta: this.altLanguages`?

Comment: Read here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60355735/5962802